# if then condition using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a pattern which goes like this

```
String1 :"String2",
```

i have to validate this pattern. here if u see there are two cases, the somestring1 can contain special characters if it is given within double quotes.

```
eg: "xxxx-xxx" :"yyyyyyyy",--------> is valid
but  xxxx-xxx  :"yyyyyyyy",--------> is not valid
    "xxxx-xxx  :"yyyyyyyy",--------> is not valid
```

So i need to create a regex which will check whether the double quotes is closed properly if it is present in String1.

Comment: Why not just count the number of `"`s?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Regex doesn't work like that.

What you can do however, is to use two separate patterns to validate:

```
\"[^\"]+?\" :.*
```

To check the one that can contain special characters, and:

```
[a-zA-Z]+? :.*
```

To check the one that can't

**EDIT:**

Thinking some more about it, you could combine the two patterns above like so:

```
^(\"[^\"]+?\"|[a-zA-Z]+?) :.*$
```

Which will match `something :"something"` and `"some-thing" :"something"` but not `"some-thing : "something"` or `some-thing : "something"`. Assuming that the string only contains the given text.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, this simple regex should work

```
\"string1\" :\"string2\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
(?<normalString>^[a-zA-Z]+$)|(?<specialString>^".*?"$)
```

This will capture only a-z characters and put them in the "normalString" group, or if there's an string within quotation marks, capture that and put it in the "specialString" group.

Comment: I don't think Java support named capture groups though.